# I cant see popover segue

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Im using xcode 4.5.2. While working in storyboard I'm trying to show popover.

But In the list of segue styles, "popover" style is not present.

[image: My segue screenshot]

Comment: It this view an iPhone view or iPad. Only the iPad support popovers.

Comment: I see, seems like this is the issue. Popover segue is only present for iPad. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only on iPad, use a actionsheet or custom view.